# Laravel can't set session variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The script never hits the route to set the session variable.

Script that sends the data that needs to be put into a session variable.

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function() {             
                var timezone = "PST";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/set_session",
                    data: { "timezone": timezone },
                    success: function(){
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            })
    </script>
```

-
Here is my route that will be used to set the session variable.

```
Route::post('/set_session', 'SetSessionsController@create');
```

-
This is my controller that sets the session.

```
class SetSessionsController extends Controller
{

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        session(['timezone' => $request->get('timezone');
    }

}
```

Comment: are there errors in the console?

Comment: Make it return your session

Comment: It something wrong with this line session(['timezone' => $request->get('timezone'); when I comment it out the ajax is successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo there:

`session(['key' => 'value']);`

So your code should be:

```
session(['timezone' => $request['timezone']]);
```

You can Access it in the blade template using:

```
@if(Session::has('timezone')))  
  {{ Session::get('timezone')}}
@endif
```

Comment: Ok now the request is successful. How would I use the session variable it in my html?